I just want to show/hide my divs, but I'm having issues with my variables. Any ideas?
I'm making a mini project for a coding class, featuring a list of poems. I set the poems in divs and the divs in a section (per a suggestion), and I want to toggle the poems' text and images so that they show or hide, and I wanted to change the button text to "Close" when shown from "Read" when hidden.
While I got some help, mainly with setting up the .forEach() method, I still can't find the solution. I've tried everything. Any other advice has been too confusing and too hard to follow.
Any help is appreciated. Thank you.
I tried using the different methods of retrieving elements from the DOM (.querySelector, .querySelectorAll, .getElementById, etc.). I tried changing the class and id names. I tried making it so I didn't shadow my variables. Literally everything.
let selection = document.querySelector(".poem")
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

// show poem or hide poem
// change text to "Read" or "Close"; if the poem is hidden, say "Read"; if it is showing, say "Close"

const readPoem = (poem) => {
  if (selection.style.display == "none") {
    selection.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    selection.style.display = "none";
  }
};

console.log()

buttons.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", (selection) => {
    if (selection.style.display == "none") {
      selection.style.display = "block";
      btn.textContent = "Close";
    } else {
      selection.style.display = "none";
      btn.textContent = "Read";
    }
  });
});


why do you have multiple buttons that show/hide one poem? what is the purpose of the function readPoem as it is never referenced? What does your HTML look like?

The purpose of readPoem is to show or hide the divs containing the poems when I click the button next to each button. I am trying to make it so that each button will successfully show or hide its respective poem, as well as change its text. Unfortunately, my code is too long to fit.

the divs ... but selection is a single element - perhaps you need to show a minimal representation of your HTML - since you talk about selection as if it were multiple divs, I would guess you have made an incorrect assumption

We can guess at an answer but without seeing your HTML structure our answers will just be guesses. Please show the HTML as we need to see how a particular button can be related to a particular poem.

Based on your description, I assume that your HTML structure is like this:
<section>
  <div class="poem-container">
    <button class="btn">Read</button>
    <div class="poem" style="display: none;">
      <!-- Poem content here -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="poem-container">
    <button class="btn">Read</button>
    <div class="poem" style="display: none;">
      <!-- Poem content here -->
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- More poem containers as needed -->
</section>

The event handler function accepts an Event object. You are passing the selection, which is not relevant.
Then we get the poem that is in the same container as the button (they are both in the .poem-container):
const poem = btn.closest(".poem-container").querySelector(".poem");

And finally, we can continue with the rest of the logic.
Here is the updated code and demo:


const buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".btn");

buttons.forEach((btn) => {
  btn.addEventListener("click", (event) => {
    // Find the associated poem div
    const poem = btn.closest(".poem-container").querySelector(".poem");

    if (poem.style.display === "none" || poem.style.display === "") {
      poem.style.display = "block";
      btn.textContent = "Close";
    } else {
      poem.style.display = "none";
      btn.textContent = "Read";
    }
  });
});
.poem-container {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 20px;
  width: fit-content;
}
<section>
  <div class="poem-container">
    <button class="btn">Read</button>
    <div class="poem" style="display: none;">
      I am a poem
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="poem-container">
    <button class="btn">Read</button>
    <div class="poem" style="display: none;">
      I am another poem
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- More poem containers as needed -->
</section>




You're close. I actually don't have the divs within divs, but maybe I should try that.
(BTW, the reason my code is so long is because my poems are long, some of them epically long.)
I'll try this as soon as I get the chance. Thanks.

I just tried the code a moment ago. Good news: It works! Not-so-good news: when I click on each button, the div containing the poem will not open right away. I have to click once and then click again to show the poems. Other than that, everything works.

Update: It works completely now. I realized that I had left something out of the condition in the if statement. Once I applied it, everything came together. Thanks so much
